# Laravel Octane Xdebug

Tags: laravel, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am faced with octane not seeing new breakpoints in code.

I am using PhpStorm + Docker (PHP 8, Xdebug 3, nginx)

After setting the breakpoint, I need to restart command and then it works:

```
php artisan octane:start --watch --host=0.0.0.0
```

Can you tell me how it should be or was I mistaken in the setting?

Additionally, I can put the command:

```
xdebug_break();
```

and it will stop and subsequent PhpStorm breakpoints will be recognized!..

Comment: Well.. On one hand, when used, [Laravel Octane](https://github.com/laravel/octane) keeps your app in memory (already compiled / "running"). When you are changing the code (e.g. by adding `xdebug_break();`) it will reload it for you `... octane:start --watch ...`.

Comment: On another hand: breakpoints are sent to Xdebug only during communication stage (e.g. when PHP starts executing the script, Xdebug kicks in and sees if it needs to initiate the debug session). During this negotiation (comms) stage is when Xdebug receives and responds to `set_breakpoint` command. You cannot set breakpoint while code is executed (e.g. in the middle of the endless loop for example), unless it's paused by the debugger and therefore in that communication stage.

Comment: So the question is: when are you trying to set those breakpoints that are not recognized? You can enable Xdebug logging and see it all there: when they are set/resolved etc. Also: https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgp (to read more on how it all works)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?